# TypeError, se espera string pero recibe numero - Angular/Express/Mongo/JS

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mongodb, express

Estoy haciendo una practica de actualizar datos en la db con mongo, directamente del api con postman si me los actualiza, desde angular cuando mando a llamar la funcion, hago consulta al error y me dice el siguiente error **TypeError: Expected a string but received a number**, en mi servicio quite el JSON.stringify pensando que era la conversion, y me sigue con lo mismo, mis modelos estan bien definidos igual, no se cual es el problema

Este es mi document.controller.js en el api

```
exports.update = (req, res) => {
    //Recoger id del documento por url
    var documentId = req.params.id;

    //Recoger datos que llegan por put
    var params = req.body;

    console.log(params);
    //Validar datos
    try {
        var validate_num_folio = !validator.isEmpty(params.num_folio);
        var validate_num_oficio = !validator.isEmpty(params.num_oficio);
        var validate_ins_juridico = !validator.isEmpty(params.ins_juridico);
        var validate_fecha_recepcion = !validator.isEmpty(params.fecha_recepcion);
        var validate_remitido = !validator.isEmpty(params.remitido);
        var validate_origen = !validator.isEmpty(params.origen);
        var validate_asignado = !validator.isEmpty(params.asignado);
        var validate_asunto = !validator.isEmpty(params.asunto);
        var validate_estatus = !validator.isEmpty(params.estatus);
        var validate_observacion = !validator.isEmpty(params.observacion);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        //TypeError: Expected a string but received a number
        return res.status(404).send({
            status: 'error',
            message: 'Faltan datos por enviar!' 
        });
    }

    if (validate_num_oficio) {
        //Find and update
        Document.findOneAndUpdate({_id: documentId}, params, {new:true}, (err, documentUpdated) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'Error al actualizar!' 
                });
            }

            if (!documentUpdated) {
                return res.status(404).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'No existe el articulo!' 
                });
            }

            return res.status(200).send({
                status: 'success',
                document: documentUpdated 
            });
        });
    } else {
        //Devolver respuesta
        return res.status(500).send({
            status: 'error',
            message: 'La validacion no es correcta!' 
        });
    }
}
```

Este es mi document.service.ts por parte de angular

```
update(id: string, document: Document): Observable<any> {
        // let params = JSON.stringify(document);
        let params = document;
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this._http.put(this.url + 'document/' + id, params, { headers: headers });
    }
```

Modelo document.ts en angular

```
export class Document{
    
    constructor(
        _id = "",
        num_folio = 1,
        num_oficio = "",
        ins_juridico = "",
        fecha_recepcion = "",
        remitido = "",
        origen = "",
        asignado = "",
        asunto = "",
        estatus = "",
        observacion = "",
        pdf_entrada = null,
        pdf_salida = null) {
            this._id = _id;
            this.num_folio = num_folio;
            this.num_oficio = num_oficio;
            this.ins_juridico = ins_juridico;
            this.fecha_recepcion = fecha_recepcion;
            this.remitido = remitido;
            this.origen = origen;
            this.asignado = asignado;
            this.asunto = asunto;
            this.estatus = estatus;
            this.observacion = observacion;
            this.pdf_entrada = pdf_entrada;
            this.pdf_salida = pdf_salida;
    }

    _id: string;
    num_folio: number;
    num_oficio: string;
    ins_juridico: string;
    fecha_recepcion: string;
    remitido: string;
    origen: string;
    asignado: string;
    asunto: string;
    estatus: string;
    observacion: string;
    pdf_entrada: null;
    pdf_salida: null;
}
```

Modelo document.models.js en el api

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const documentSchema = new Schema({ 
    num_folio : { type : Number, required: true },
    num_oficio : { type : String, required : true },
    ins_juridico : { type : String, required : true },
    fecha_recepcion : { type : String, required : true },
    remitido : { type : String, required : true },
    origen : { type : String, required : true },
    asignado : { type : String, required : true, max : [127, "Max Length is 127 characters"] },
    asunto : { type : String, required : true, max : [127, "Max Length is 127 characters"] },
    estatus : { type : String, required : true, max : [127, "Max Length is 127 characters"] },
    observacion : { type : String, required : false },
    pdf_entrada : { type: String, required : false },
    pdf_salida : { type: String, required : false }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Document', documentSchema);
```

Componente del submit para editar

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log("hola");

    this._documentService.update(this.doc._id,this.doc).subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.status === 'Success') {
          this.status = 'success';
          this.doc = response.documentUpdated;
          this._router.navigate(['ControlGestion/Inicio']);
        } else {
          // console.log(response);
          // this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
          //   location.reload();
          // });
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error,"Es el error");
        this.status = 'error';
      }
    );
    // console.log(this.doc);
  }[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

---

Se me habia pasado poner la imagen del navegador y del api, es parte de mi pregunta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactamente tienes toda la estructura correcta, el problema lo tienes en el primer bloque de código que has pasado:

> var validate_num_folio = !validator.isEmpty(params.num_folio);

Te está crasheando porque **validator.isEmpty solo admite strings como parámetros**, de ahí el error, ya que esperaba un string en vez de un número al ser params.num_folio de tipo number.

Tienes **2 posibles** soluciones, una sería convertir a string esta variable en esa misma línea:

```
const validate_num_folio = !validator.isEmpty(`${params.num_folio}`);
```

Y la otra que te proporciona [la documentación](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) de la librería, y en este caso tiene más sentido siendo un valor numérico, es utilizar:

```
const validate_num_folio = !validator.isInt(`${params.num_folio}`);
```

Como nota adicional, para mejorar el código, recuerda siempre utilizar let o const para declarar variables, siendo const el preferente por tema performance y espacio en memoria.

Comment: la verdad si me sirvio bastante, ya me actualiza los datos, ya solo tengo que ver un warning de mongoose pero ya es aparte, muchas gracias